# Get the new filename after uploading with uploadify

Tags: uploadify, backend

I have uploadify working nicely. When the back-end php is loaded the filename is uploaded with new filename and which is entered in the database using a new unique id.

How can I send the new filename back to the page that contains the form?

Answer (score 0):

There you go :-

```
'onUploadComplete' : function(file, response, data) {
                                        alert('The File ' + file.name + " has been uploaded with response "+response);
                                                $('#brandImage'+i).val(file.name);
                                                i++;
                            }
```

you can use `response` parameter to send filename and use it to your html :)